# C# WPF set build property in project programmatically

Tags: c#

[image]

I need to change the recommended 32 bits checkbox to true or false alternately code behind

Comment: Please post code what you tried so far

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change the Prefer 32Bit checkbox using code because it's written to the CorFlags section of the assembly's header.

You can view that using the [corflags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699(v=vs.110).aspx) available with your Visual Studio install:

[image]

Comment: Okay,thanks,how to display the result like you on corflags.exe,what is the command you typed?

Comment: The command is CorFlags.exe (in the Visual Studio Developer command prompt). You can find it here: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\CorFlags.exe"` or similar depending on your installation folder and/or OS.